# Having two idenctical Canvas, same code to draw, one of them is empty

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, line

I have recently started exploring world of WPF and I'm now writing a program that writes guitar tabs. You press on a fret, bellow appears tabs. I hope you get the main idea. I have two Canvas : on one of them I draw fretboard (bunch of vertical and horizontal lines), on another one I draw tabs. This is my XAML code :

```
<Window x:Class="TabsPro.Natos"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabsPro"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Natos" Height="372.049" Width="789.285">
    <Canvas>
        <Canvas Height="86" Width="600" Name="fretBoard" Background="Blue" Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="24" Loaded="Natos_Loaded"/>
        <Canvas Height="114" Width="720" Name="tabs" Background="Green" Canvas.Left="33" Canvas.Top="165"/>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

That's how I create a line :

```
for (int strings = 1; strings < 7; strings++)
{
     for (int frets = 1; frets < 25; frets++)
     {
          Line fretHorizontalLine = new Line();
          fretHorizontalLine.MouseUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Notes.fretHL_MouseUp);                  
          fretHorizontalLine.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
          fretHorizontalLine.StrokeThickness = 4;
          fretHorizontalLine.Stroke = silverBrush;
          fretHorizontalLine.X1 = posX1H;
          fretHorizontalLine.Y1 = posY1H;
          fretHorizontalLine.X2 = posX2H;
          fretHorizontalLine.Y2 = posY1H;
          fretHorizontalLine.Name = "fret" + fretCounter.ToString();
          fretHorizontalList.Add(fretHorizontalLine);
          posX1H += 25;
          posX2H += 25;
          fretCounter++;
     }
     posY1H += 16;
     posX1H = 2;
     posX2H = 25;
}
```

I then use delegate to  pass list "fretHorizontalList" which is then used to draw fretboard (there is also a second list but code is identical, except there is no event created). When WPF is loaded, in method Loaded I add children to first Canvas from that these lists. As you probably noticed I create event Mouse_Up. To put it simple, it to draw tabs on the second Canvas. This is the code :

```
public void fretHL_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Line fretLine = sender as Line;
    ManageDatabase ManageDB = new ManageDatabase();
    PassFretName passFretName = new PassFretName(ManageDB.FretNameHandler);
    passFretName(fretLine.Name.ToString());
    GenerateDrawings generateDWGS = new GenerateDrawings();
    generateDWGS.InitiateTabGeneration();
    DrawTabs();
}
```

InitiateTabGeneration method just creates lines and a textblock, then delegate is used to pass these things to xaml.cs. And then I just read from the list and add children to second Canvas. Now the problem is : lines and a textblock won't appear. IsVisible and IsLoaded give me "false". I then did kind of a test : in method Loaded I add horizontal lines to first Canvas and vertical lines to the second Canvas(the one I can't draw on). Everything works fine. I then tried to add children when second Canvas is loaded. Again, everything is fine. What is the thing that I do wrong? I've been searching for solutions for the past two days but the only thing I found was Opacity. I tried changing it's values but that didn't help.

If it's a duplicate I am sorry and please provide me a link to that question. Also, I am a begginer and I understand that there might be a lot of mistakes. I appreciate any comments on what should be done better.

P.S. This is my first post and if there is anything wrong with it please tell me so I can do better in future.

Have a nice day!

**EDIT:**

[There's the picture of how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k93PH.png)

Blue Canvas is fretboard. When you click on a line (fret) tabs should be displayed on a green Canvas.

**EDIT2:**

Code that is in method InitiateTabGeneration :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        Line testLine = new Line();
        testLine.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        testLine.Stroke = silverBrush;
        testLine.StrokeThickness = 3;
        testLine.X1 = x1;
        testLine.X2 = x2;
        testLine.Y1 = y1;
        testLine.Y2 = y1;
        testLine.Name = "tab" + i.ToString();
        tabLineList.Add(testLine);

        x1 += 10;
        x2 += 10;
        y1 += 10;
    }

    TextBlock tbTest = new TextBlock();
    tbTest.Text = "1";
    Canvas.SetLeft(tbTest, (x2 - x1) / 2);
    Canvas.SetTop(tbTest, y1);

    PassTabs passTabs = new PassTabs(Notes.GetTabs);
    passTabs(tabLineList, tabNumber);
}
```

This lines are not the actual ones that I would generate after someone clicks on fret. I just wrote these for testing.

Comment: `FrameworkElement` in wpf can have only one [`Parent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.parent(v=vs.110).aspx). Are you creating 2 different sets of shapes (`Line`s) for each `Canvas`?

Comment: There are seperate lists for each "type" of line if it's that what you asked.

Comment: Can u try to explain with an image.

Comment: Done. Green Canvas remains empty after I press on a fret. foreach loop has runs through the list but nothing appears.

Comment: Could you post the code for your `InitiateTabGeneration` method? You said that's where the lines and text blocks are being created. I suspect your problem will lie somewhere in that method.

Comment: Sure. I create these lines just like when I create fretboard.

Comment: @MrMatas I don't see anywhere in that code where you actually add your TextBlock and Line elements to a Canvas. You _are_ setting the `Left` and `Top` properties, but you also need to do something like `theCanvas.Children.Add(testLine)` where "theCanvas" is the name of your canvas element.

Comment: Oh, you wanted to see that part. I pass this list to xaml.cs class, then in method DrawFrets I just use `foreach` and add every line just like you said -`tabs.Children.Add(line)` .

Comment: @MrMatas Without seeing the rest of your code and XAML in context I think this is going to be difficult to resolve on StackOverflow. I would double-check that you are adding the elements to the correct Canvas, and also that your `Left` and `Top` properties are actually being set to the values you think they are. There is also an app called _Snoop_ which you can download and use to check what elements are in a Window's visual tree, that may help.

Comment: @StevenRands I forgot to mention that I also can't add figures to blue Canvas if I try to add them like I  add to green one. Seems like I can add figures to both Canvas only if I add it in Loaded, MouseUp/Down, etc. I hope you understand what I mean. Anyway, thanks for help. I'll try an app you suggested.